# Is there a general method of calculating remainder of these systems?

Tags: number-theory

If I want to calculate remainder when $x$ divides $a^b$,is there some general method to do this calculation. Normally I try to use binomial or totient function, but other than that I pretty much am not able to solve these kind of questions, thanks for your help

Comment: I do not understand your question, dou want to calculate $a^b \mod x$?

Comment: Yes I wanted to calculate $a^b\modx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for, but I think the following is some sort of standard procedure, part of which you already mentioned.

Since Euler's theorem states that $a^{\phi(x)}\equiv 1\mod x $, we can look at the remainder $r$ obtained from dividing $b$ by $\phi(x)$, i.e. $r\equiv b\mod\phi(x)$. We then have that $a^b\equiv a^r\mod x$. Often there are nice tricks available to calculate this, but if there isn't, or if you don't see any, you can write $r$ in binary and use this. First, say $r=\sum_{i=0}^l r_i2^i$ where each $r_i\in\{0,1\}$. Then $a^r=a^{\sum r_i2^i}=\prod a^{r_i2^i}$. Since it is easy to find the successive values of $a^{2^i}$ by squaring the previous one ($(a^{2^i})^2=a^{2^{i+1}} $), one can easily calculate $a^r$.

Since this may not be the easiest to read, I will give an example. Suppose we want to calculate $3^{11}\mod 13$. We can first write $11=8+2+1$. By repeatedly squaring $3$ we find that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
3^1 &=& 3,\\
3^2 &=& 3^2 = 9,\\
3^4 &=& 9^2 \equiv 3,\\
3^8 &=& 3^2 \equiv 9,
\end{eqnarray*}
and thus $3^{11}=3^{8+2+1}=3^83^23^1 \equiv 9\cdot 9\cdot 3 \equiv 9\mod 13$.

Is this more or less what you were looking for?

Comment: That was very nice